# Why doesn't it add a new TableHeaderCell?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I would like to add an a new TableHeaderCell. Because I don't have the time to learn vb, I only used a converter, so I don't know if the fault happened there. This is my code so far. It does execute this section but it won't add the header to the ASP.NET GridView. I'm using asp:BoundField.

```
if (grdvProductChurn != null)
{
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
    TableCell left = new TableHeaderCell();
    left.ColumnSpan = 2;
    row.Cells.Add(left);

    TableCell totals = new TableHeaderCell();
    totals.ColumnSpan = grdvProductChurn.Columns.Count - 2;
    totals.Text = "Anzahl";
    row.Cells.Add(totals);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your remark about vb. Was this source converted from vb? Are you going to convert this _to_ vb?

Comment: There is already a site, but it's written in vb and know I do it in C#

Comment: @freefaller Do I need to add it to the GridView or what do you mean?